# Sitecore 7.2 - Maintenance Mode setting

Tags: site-configuration

We will be doing some site updates and testing in relation to an update to our AMS system, and would like to put our live SC site in Maintenance Mode, a setting we see under the site settings, while we update everything and test.  I can't find anything about the mode yet, though - how it works, how content authors can test, etc.  I tried setting our test site in Maintenance Mode, and it does not appear to make a difference; it still comes up as expected.  Are there any resources on this setting in SDN or other location?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, "maintenance mode" is not a native feature of Sitecore. Can you provide a list of modules that you are using, and/or search your `<site_host>/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx` for the word "maintenance" and see what pops up?

Comment: Zachary - I checked ShowConfig.aspx, and all of the 'maintenance' references shown refer to ContentSearch - rebuilding indexes for the DBs, that kind of thing.

Comment: Interesting. How about if you search your solution? Is there anything in custom code that references it? Try searching the Sitecore Client, as well.

Comment: You are correct, Zach - it is a module inserted by our third party SC provider.  Working with them to suss out the functionality and such - it does work, after a fashion, once the internal config file for it is properly referenced.  Thanks for the help!  I found a reference to it while searching out a separate issue on too-long-file-names, with 'MaintenanceMode' popping up in a _upgradeHistory directory, and then backtracked it from there.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Zachary was correct - the Maintenance Mode function appearing in SC was part of the core installation done by our third-party SC provider. Still with them on full functionality, but it appears to be a good tool to have, just in case. Full reference to it was found in a subfolder under app_config.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem ;) Just be sure to accept your answer in a few days when the option becomes available.